# Is it ok to use "apprehend" as a synonym of "understand"?

Tags: vocabulary

> Modern physicists do not apprehend classic astrophysics.

Is it ok to use "apprehend" with the meaning of "understand"?

Comment: It's a bit old fashioned and formal, and many younger or less educated people might not immediately understand it.

Comment: No, it really isn't, normally. And Chagas is a great mushroom. One can apprehend a notion but not how the universe works.

Comment: Just forget about this outdated / formal / literary sense of ***apprehend***, and always use ***comprehend***. And don't let anyone tell you that those two words have subtly difference implications that would "justify" using the less common one in certain circumstances. Whatever that justification might be, it's unlikely your audience / readers will be aware of it, and interpret your vocabulary choice accordingly.

Comment: 'Tis thine own choice to make, but thou hast been advised! :)

Comment: I disagree with the answers saying you can't use 'apprehend' in this way. Yes, it is a little bit highfalutin for everyday conversation, but I wouldn't be surprised at all to see 'apprehend' used this way in a literary work.

Comment: I don't think it's highfalutin, I think it's flat out silly sounding. And I fail to see how you will criticize physicists not understanding the universe by using something flowery.

Comment: @d_b - especially a literary work written before about 1800.

Comment: I don't understand what makes it "flowery". Is it because it's somewhat uncommon nowadays? That doesn't make a word flowery.

Answer (score 2):

This sense of "apprehend" is perfectly acceptable although a bit formal. I see it used in scientific works and formal essays. It might not fit well in casual conversation Many fluent speakers might think it odd or even fail to understand it.

Comment: In modern usage "apprehend" usually means "arrest" and "apprehension" means "worry". If you use the word in the way you are proposing many people will think you have made a mistake.